# file replace() Method

Tags: python, email

I have an email that I want to send to 6 people. I need to create a separate txt file for each recipient and replace `"[name]"` in the letter with each recipient name. This is my code and I am stuck. When I try and replace `"name"`, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Any help please?

My code is as follows:

```
with open("Input/Letters/starting_letter.txt") as l:
        the_letter = l.readlines()

with open("Input/Names/invited_names.txt") as names:
    the_names = names.readlines()

for letter in range(6):
    with open(f"Output/letter_{letter}.txt", mode="a") as file:
        file.writelines(the_letter)
        file.replace("name", f"{the_names[letter]}")
```

Comment: Replace works on str, l.readlines() gives you list of lines, you can use l.read() instead

Comment: There is no file `replace()` method, as the error message indicates. If you want to change something in the middle of a file, you generally have to re-write the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

You should be replacing in `the_letter` before writing to the file.

There's no need to split the letter into lines. Read it as a single string so you can replace in the entire thing without a loop.

You forgot the `[]` in your `.replace()` call.

```
with open("Input/Letters/starting_letter.txt") as l:
    the_letter = l.read()

with open("Input/Names/invited_names.txt") as names:
    the_names = names.readlines()

for letter, name in enumerate(the_names)
    with open(f"Output/letter_{letter}.txt", mode="a") as file:
        file.write(the_letter.replace("[name]", name.strip)
```

Comment: Thank you. this was helpful. Alternatively after struggling the following also worked for me:

 ` with open("Input/Names/invited_names.txt") as names_file: names = names_file.readlines() with open("Input/Letters/starting_letter.txt") as letter_file: letter_content = letter_file.read() for name in names: stripped_name = name.strip() new_letter =letter_content.replace("[name]", stripped_name) with open(f"Output/ReadyToSend/letter_for_{stripped_name}.txt", mode="a") as ready_letter: ready_letter.write(new_letter) `

Comment: It's nearly impossible to read code in comments. I can't tell what you've done differently.

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace works on str, `l.readlines()` gives you list of lines, you can use `l.read()` instead
2. not file.replace("name", f"{the_names[letter]}"), instead
   `file.write(the_letter.replace("name", name.strip())`

Answer (score 0):

Splitting letter by end of line make it harder later to change name. read method reads file as a one string.

Reading names to separate lines is correct, you will then iterate on a list returned in this step.

Then as a final step code is writing to files modified string. `[name]` is replaced with name from file. If there's `\n` at the end of string it is deleted.

Code:

```
with open("Input/Letters/starting_letter.txt") as l:
        the_letter = l.read()

with open("Input/Names/invited_names.txt") as names:
    the_names = names.readlines()

for letter in range(6):
    with open(f"Output/letter_{letter}.txt", mode="a") as file:
        file.write(the_letter.replace("[name]", f"{the_names[letter]}".replace('\n','')))
```